# calculating sqare root without use of square root function in c++

Tags: c++

You are required to write your own algorithm for computing square root. Write a
pseudocode rst before you go on and write the C++ program. Do not use the
sqrt function from the math library to compute the square root. Create your own
square root algorithm.
2. Your program should cater for all non-perfect square numbers as well as negative
integers that the user inputs. In these cases the program should prompt the user
that a perfect square has not been entered.
3. The program should allow the user three chances to enter a perfect square. If the
user is not able to enter a perfect square within the three chances then the program
should exit.
4. You are to use functions in your C++ program. Create a user dened function
by the name sqroot. This should be the function where you implement your own
square root algorithm. This function should return an integer and accept only one
input argument, that too of type integer.

i have tried but got stuck pliz help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    int test;
    int square;
    int answer;
    int i=0;

    cout << "enter a perfect sqare ";
    cin >> square;

    answer = pow(square, 0.5);

    test = square % answer;
    if (test==0){
        cout << "the square is: " << answer;

    }

    if (test!=0){

        cout << "enter a perfect sqare ";
        cin >> square;  
        answer = pow(square, 0.5);

        test = square % answer;
        cout << "the square is: " << answer;
    }










return 0;
```

}

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Comment: I don't know if you are allowed to use pow function from math library. Also, be clear with your question, where did you get stuck?

Comment: place where the user enters a non perfect square number and the user should be given 3 chances. pow  function is allowed

Comment: I don't think using pow() will make your professor happy.

Comment: so what else can i do?

Comment: Approximate it. Start with something like num / 2 and adjust it until squaring it gives you the supplied number. Or you could try implementing one of the methods of computing square roots but I doubt that's the exercise here.

Comment: The obvious way to compute square roots if you are always dealing with perfect squares is to use brute force.  The simplest way would be to start at 1 and keep incrementing by 1, and see if that number squared equals the number to be rooted (if the square of the increment is higher than the number to find the square root of, you know it is not a perfect square).  There's probably a way to find a more efficient lower bound programmatically, but at least that can start you off.

Comment: I just love the Q_rsqrt from Quake. No human entity is ever expected to fully comprehend it, but it is still pretty awesome: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to impress da' Prof, you could use the binomial expansion approximation with a power of 1/2:

[image]

[image]

= [image]

*a* is the next perfect square from your input number (I'm sure it'll be easy for you to compute that, and its square root). Sub it into the formula, with *x* as your input number, not forgetting to use floating point variables for the fractions, and do what you like with the answer (in your case round it to an integer).

I know it's only an approximation but it should be more than good enough for integer answers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 1):

See [Newton-Raphson algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number)

From Wikipedia: "a method for finding successively better approximations to the roots (or zeroes) of a real-valued function".
Lets say you are trying to find the root of 'a'. 
Then basically, you are trying to find the roots of the function:
f(x) = x^2 - a

Also this method is known to be very fast.